# How works delayed standby to recover wals

Tags: postgresql

Which mechanism is used for a delayed standby to recover wals. Processes that usually use streaming are not present (wal_sender/wal_receiver). Does the deferred standby fetch the wals one after another based on its offset from the primary or barman if it is configured

Comment: Are you asking about recovery_min_apply_delay or something else?

Comment: yes, I configure recovery_min_apply_delay to 60 min